# Update variable blade template

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, variables, laravel-blade

I'm trying update a variable respect of sprint to fill a table with tasks of the selected sprint.

This is a tag for select sprint:

```
@foreach($project->sprints as $s)
    <a href="#" >{{$s->version}}</a>
@endforeach
```

Next, the table of tasks:

```
@php ($sprint = null)
@if($sprint != null)
   <table class="table table-striped">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                ...
            </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
            @foreach($sprints->tasks as $task)
               <tr>
                   ...
               </tr>
            @endforeach
       </tbody>            
   </table>
@else
...
```

How to assign $s to $sprint?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? there is now where in your code where `$s` interacts with `$sprint`

Comment: Mike, i need assign `$s` to `$sprint` for to fill the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must handle the selected sprint in the controller.

Let's suppose you have defined:

- Route

  ```
  Route::get('/project/{projectId}', [
      'uses' => 'ProjectController@show',
      'as' => 'showProject'
  ])
  ```
- Controller

  ```
  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
  use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  use App\Project;

  class ProjectControllerextends Controller
  {
      public function show(int $projectId, Request $request)
      {
          $project = Project::with(['sprints.tasks'])->find($projectId);

          $selectedSprint = $request->query('selectedSprint')

          if (!empty($selectedSprint)) {
              $selectedSprint = $project->sprints->first(function($sprint) use ($selectedSprint) {
                  return $sprint->id === (int) $selectedSprint;
              });
          }

          return view('projects.show', ['project' => $project, 'selectedSprint' => $selectedSprint]);
      }
  }
  ```
- View

  ```
  @foreach($project->sprints as $s)
      <a href="{{route('showProject', ['projectId' => $project->id, 'selectedSprint' => $s->id])}}">
          {{$s->version}}
      </a>
  @endforeach

  @if($selectedSprint != null)
     <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
              <tr>
                  ...
              </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              @foreach($selectedSprint->tasks as $task)
                 <tr>
                     ...
                 </tr>
              @endforeach
         </tbody>            
     </table>
  @else
  ```

Comment: I would like $ s to be assigned dynamically to $ sprint without having to go to the server

Comment: well you can't. The only possible way would be to use Javascript but it would be too complex for such a simple thing

Comment: very difficult? because i need that not refresh page

Comment: yes because you have several collections: springs and tasks.. those collections must be stored in js in order to update that table WITH JS